# Run a jar file permanent on v-server

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I just bought a vserver and now I'm trying to run a jar file on it permanently.
The problem is, that if I connect to my vserver via PuTTY, the sessions ends when I close the program and that kills my program. How can I open a terminal sessions where I can run my jar file and which never stops? I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on my server

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`nohup [your command and parameters] &`

`nohup` is a unix command that means 'no hangup', so it won't kill the session when you disconnect.

The `&` means 'run this command as a background process'. That will let you disconnect without having to kill the program.

Here's more info on `nohup` : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup

In the longer-term you'll likely want to install the app as a service to start when you reboot the machine. The way to do so will depend on the flavor of unix/linux you have.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use `nohup`, `screen`, `tmux` or create a `systemd` service unit.